# Repeating items in a dropdownlist on postback in .net

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with 6 items.When an item selected in the dropdownlist, a gridview binded with some data. It works correctly.But on postback the items in the dropdownlist repeates.The code written in page_load event.

```
 string m = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
        string y = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(m + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
         string date = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        connect con = new connect(date);
        IList<connect.Session> records = con.getToken();
        GridView1.DataSource = records;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Wrap all the code when not post back. `if(!Page.Ispostback){//Your code}`

Comment: Does `DropDownList1` have `AutoPostBack="true"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Page.IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-property to check the if the page loads the first time or not. Otherwise you don't need to `DataBind` the `GridView` again due to enabled `ViewState`.

So in `Page_Load`:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   // code above 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic usage of Page.IsPostBack is data binding / control initialization.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   //Control Initialization
   //Databinding
}
```

Things that are persisted on ViewState and ControlState don't need to be recreated on every postback so you check for this condition in order to avoid executing unnecessary code.

Another classic usage is getting and processing Querystring parameters. You don't need to do that on postback.

```
Load(){ //Page load
if(!Page.IsPostBack){ // skips the execution of below lines during the next time.
 string m = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
        string y = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(m + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).Month.ToString().Equals("January"))
            y = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).ToString("MMMM") + " " + y);
         string date = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        connect con = new connect(date);
        IList<connect.Session> records = con.getToken();
        GridView1.DataSource = records;
 }}
```